# Blank admin panel | Drupal 7 | XAMPP

Tags: 7

I am migrating a Drupal 7 project from one PC to another and I did the following steps

> 1) Copy pasted the root folder into `D:\XAMPP\htdocs` 
>    2)
>   Imported the database of that project into phpmyadmin (had to increase
>   `max_file_uploads` to 20 in `php.ini`)
>   3) reset admin password
>   by referring https://drupal.org/node/1023428
>   4) updated the
>   password in `settings.php`
>   5) cleared cache in the imported db
>   (by deleting the content of cache and cache_* tables)

Now I am able to login but the admin panel is blank, When I click *Dashboard, Content, Structure, Appearance* etc. nothing appears

No error is console.

PS: this is the first time I am using Drupal, so in-depth instructions is much appreciated

**Edit**

After [@Randell](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/1134/randell)'s suggestion I had set `display_errors` to `on` and `error_reporting` to `E_ALL`. Still no error appears anywhere

**Edit**
From `watchdog` the last two rows;

Second-Last row

> uid : 1
>  Message : Session opened for %name.
>  location :
>   `http://localhost:81/mysite/user`
>  referer :
>   `http://localhost:81/mysite/user`

Last Row

> uid : 0
>  Message : Attempting to re-run cron while it is already
>   running.
>  location : `http://localhost:81/mysite/users/admin`
>   referer : `http://localhost:81/mysite/user`

Comment: How did you cleared the cache in the imported db?  by truncate cache_ tables?

Comment: I used `delete from table_name` query

Comment: Make sure you have `display_errors` ON in your `php.ini` so you can see the error messages instead of a blank page.

Comment: @Randell, Did that now, not seeing any errors

Comment: And make sure `error_reporting` is set to `E_ALL`. Restart the server after the changes to `php.ini`.

Comment: Still no error appearing

Comment: @rps - Make sure to clear data from from all cache tables. cache_

Comment: yes I cleared all cache tables

Comment: Have you checked that `www.example.com/?q=admin` is working or not?

Comment: @JayendraKainthola nope. only `?q=user` works

Comment: @rps, then your admin details are not correct. What is _User Id_ of the user which is logged into site?

Comment: admin, uid: 1, rid: 3(administrator), I tried changing rid to 4(superadmin), still issue persisted

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it is the `memory_limit` setting in your php.ini. Drupal 7 needs a bit more memory and depending on how many modules you are using, it must be set to a higher value. 64M or 128M should be enough for moderate sites.

Comment: It is set to 128M and is working in the PC the project was imported from

Answer (score 0):

Increase PHP memory limit

If you need more than 128M:

Add the line
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
to your [Drupal 7 root]/sites/default/settings.php file.

check php_value memory_limit in php.ini